# Rose tip got brown burn quilted and dropped rose head

Tags: diseases, planting, insects, roses, trellis

I bought this rose from David Austin last year

https://www.davidaustinroses.com/us/the-poet-s-wife-shrub-rose

Every since it was fine until I check it today in May 25 (I am in Pacific Northwest)

[image]

It was like burning on top and the rose head dropped out. Everywhere else is fine except that branch. So something delibrately attacked that area.

Is it an animal? Bug? What is the cause?

**UPDATE**

I have another rose and it did similar thing:

[image]

This one is climbing rose. So is it because it's too tall and cannot support itself?

Comment: The rosebud damage looks like aphids, but surely they should still be around.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is caused by a disease called rose rosette:

https://agrilifeextension.tamu.edu/library/landscaping/rose-rosette-disease-demystified/

My best understanding is 1) it can't be cured/fixed; 2) plant is a total loss and need to be quickly removed, or 3) it will spread to all other rose plants in the general vicinity (if it hasn't already).

Comment: I am not sure if this is the case. My plant grew back up again.
From other reading, this seems to be caused by lack of nutrient like calcium. I don't know. What I know is that in Pacific Northwest we have a lot of rain and the nutrient got flushed down with the water like toilet.

Comment: @HP. I agree with this answer. It definitely is a pest damage. Had it been nutrient deficiency, it would've been more uniform throughout the plant and not just confined to a small portion. The best you can confirm is by cutting the branch and checking if it's hollow. It is in early stages. Then checking the leaves and foliage and petals with a magnifying glass. If there's presence of small insects, the best you can do is cut the affected parts, burn them away and then treat entire plant with semi-concentrated solution of cypermethrin